# How Do I Get richTextBox1.Lines Cross-Threading Saftly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, richtextbox

I need to get `richTextBox1.Lines` in another thread. But I don't know how to cross thread saftly to get it.

```
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
```

Comment: Just don't.  Pass it as an argument to Thread.Start().  A worker thread randomly reading properties from a control that the user can change while it is running just never comes to a good end.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Hans, you should properly pass it into your thread, from the main UI thread.

...but, because everyone enjoys a long, hard to read one-liner:

```
        List<string> lines = new List<string>((string[])richTextBox1.Invoke(new Func<string[]>(delegate { return richTextBox1.Lines; } )) );
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check msdn help about RichTextBox.BeginInvoke(Delegate) which is inherited from Control.BeginInvoke.